# Is there really an error, or does my server not support PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As I was advised I have changed from mySQL to PDO calls yet I can't seem to get past accessing the actual database as below

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=info;charset=UTF-8", 'admin', 'xxxxxx');
```

as it returns

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in db.php on line 8
```

I have checked through forums and from what I've read the server does support PDO , furthermore `phpinfo()` is disabled for security reasons so I can't turn to that, Have i actualy made an error in the string or does it mean my server does not yet support PDO ?

Comment: Could be a dumb question, but is admin a variable? because they should be strings if not or have $ if they are.

Comment: admin is the actual username and when in quotes i get the same error

Comment: Try to rewrite the whole line. Just type it again carefully from scratch and delete the old line completely.

Comment: Read the error message again. It says that the variable on line 8 is unexpected. This means something before that line is wrong. Update your question and show lines 1 through 8 also.

Comment: I did as @budwiser said to rewrite and it's working :/

Comment: The only T_VARIABLE in that line is `$db`. If the parser says it's unexpected, you need to look at the code *right before* this line - you most likely missed a `;` in the previous line or something similar.

Comment: :/ I've completely re-written everything but I'll make sure next time i check lines before, thanks for the heads up :) DCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try rewriting the problematic line from scratch and delete the old line completely. I've had several issues, where I'm facing `unexpected T_VARIABLE` - error with no obvious reason. I think it's because I've managed to use some kind of key combination on my laptop's keyboard, which causes some non-visible character to get amongst my code.

After rewriting the line, the problem is usually gone.

Answer (score 0):

The last two parameters should be encapsulated in single quotes, or be variables themselves. Ie (new PDO("stuffhere", $user, $pass)

**EDIT**
Try this: [How to check if PDO support is enabled in my Apache Installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087965/how-to-check-if-pdo-support-is-enabled-in-my-apache-installation)

```
if (!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
    echo 'PDO unavailable';
}
elseif (defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')) {
    echo 'PDO available';
}
```

Comment: yes when using mysql_* functions they work fine :) but i was told to move away from using it

Comment: Yes you should Try the code I edited above. This will check the environment and ensure PDO is available to you.

Comment: I think the code you have given isn't very good as it returned PDO unavailable and I now have fixed the issue and it is working as normal

Comment: That's too bad. Glad you got it fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a better idea of what part of a line has an error you can split it onto multiple lines. e.g.

```
 8. $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=info;charset=UTF-8", 'admin', 'xxxxxx');
```

Could be changed to:

```
 8. $db = new PDO(
 9. "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=info;charset=UTF-8",
10. 'admin',
11. 'xxxxxx');
```

And now the line that the error is reported on could be 8, 9, 10 or 11 and you'll know more precisely what's wrong.

Comment: `8.$dty = 
9.new PDO(
10."mysql:host=localhost;dbname=info", 
11.'admin', 
12.'xxxx'
);` still gets me same error :/