# Mysql update statement won't execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can somebody help me with this? When i'm trying to update my table nothing happens and I can't figure out what's wrong. I've tried different query's but not 1 worked.

My code: http://pastebin.com/8zDpm0Ah it doesn't work from line 23

```
<?php

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE ID LIKE '$ID'") as $row){

    echo "Titel: <input type='text' size='50' name='titel' value='$row[titel]'><br>";
    echo "Post:<br>";
    echo "<textarea name='editblog'>";
    echo $row[post];
    echo "</textarea>";

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='ID' value='";
    echo $row[ID];
    echo "'>";
}
?>

<input type="submit" value="Edit post" name="postedit">
</form>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editblog' );
</script>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['postedit'])){
    $titel = $_POST['titel'];
    $post = $_POST['editblog'];
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];

    $STH = $db->prepare("UPDATE blog SET titel='$titel',post='$post' WHERE ID=$ID");  
    $STH->execute();
    echo "<h2>Post edited!</h2>";
}
```

Comment: What is the error you have? there is no error?

Comment: be sure the id is passed into the variable $ID, if the variable is empty in where clause the update will do nothing

Comment: Can you do a print_r($_POST) so we can actually see if everything is passed as expected?

Comment: For this query : **SELECT * FROM blog WHERE ID LIKE '$ID'** why using LIKE instead '=' ?

Comment: was using = before but I really tried changing anything to let it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using prepared statements as they were intended (using `$db->bind_params()`), then I recommend switching line 29 to

```
$STH = $db->query("UPDATE blog SET titel='$titel',post='$post' WHERE ID=$ID");
```

and removing line 30.

Comment: Only placeholders should be used in prepared statement and not variables.

Comment: This statement isn't a prepared statement, it's executing a raw query string.

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** at all using parameterized queries, switching to PDO, does not mean only changing `mysql_query()` to `$db->prepare()` It is a little bit more than that.  while using PDO, you can't place every variable in your query, I am talking about this code:

```
$STH = $db->prepare("UPDATE blog SET titel='$titel',post='$post' WHERE ID=$ID");  
                                $STH->execute();
```

The values, `$title, $post and $id` need to be replaced as `?` in your query, and later can be executed.

So, try the following.:

```
if(isset($_POST['postedit'])) {
     $title = $_POST['titel'];
     $post = $_POST['editblog'];
     $id = $_POST['ID'];
    try {
    $STH = $db->prepare("UPDATE blog SET titel = ?, post = ? WHERE ID = ? ");  
    $STH->execute(array($title, $post, $id));
    } catch(PDOExeption $e){
     echo 'The error is: '. $e->getMessage();
    }
    if($STH->rowCount() > 0){
       echo 'data updated successfuly';
    }else{
       echo 'data updating failed';
    }
}
```

**Debugging:**

```
    <?php
    $title = 'I am post title';
    $post = 'I am POST';
    $id = '17';

    try {
    new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=addictus_db", "addictus_admin", "dikketetten");
    $STH = $db->prepare("UPDATE blog SET titel = ?, post = ? WHERE ID = ? ");  
    $STH->execute(array($title, $post, $id));
    } catch(PDOExeption $e){
     echo 'The error is: '. $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: @YoshiPeters Did you copy and replace it with the code you have?

Comment: Ok, just updated it. Now, make sure `1` your are posting the three fields, and `2` your `$db` is not empty. it should be something like `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=xxxx', 'xxx', 'xxx')` ofcourse, the `xxx` should be replaced by your actual dbname, user, pass. try it again @YoshiPeters

Comment: $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=addictus_db", 'addictus_admin', 'dikketetten'); this is my $db and I'm pretty sure I'm posting all 3 things.

Comment: Stick with either `'single quotes'` or `"double quotes"` you are mixing the two in your database

Comment: I copy pasted the entire piece of code and replaced it, it just does nothing.

Comment: @YoshiPeters I have added another code, called `debugging` you should create a **NEW** file, paste the code, the refresh the page once. don't add anything to it. just run it and check, your database rows after it. It will tell you if there is a problem

Comment: Well, then your database does not support PDO drivers. check **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9799716/1640606)** to know, if you have PDO or not

Comment: I"m using PDO for all my other database things and all of them work except this thing, and I just checked it with the link you provided it says: "PDO available".

Comment: Then, I am sure it is updating, you are not just going and checking maybe. go to phpMyadmin and check the rows individually

Comment: yeah it did update! I just had to change the ID to something in my db.

Comment: @YoshiPeters Glad it's working for you. Make sure to accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yeah it updates that constant variable so prob something wrong in my post then?

Comment: @YoshiPeters yes, You were not using `?` place holders so, I changed your code, you can see the block of code, before the debugging

Comment: that still doesn't work, it works with the constant like the debugging but when i change it to the other code it doesn't update anything :(

Comment: check the post, whether you are posting or not. and include the connection object inside `if(isset(POST[])){//here`  this is a simple problem, if you don't try to figure out simple problems like this, it will take you a long time to get to know php